# [Android][CTS] SimpleSignatureTest Error. What XML does this test compare?

Tags: java, android, junit

Problem: I am not sure where and what xml file this cts test is comparing against.

When I run this particular CTS test case `run cts -p android.tests.sigtest`

it fails and complains as follows:

```
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner: failed: testSignature(android.tests.sigtest.SimpleSignatureTest)
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner: ----- begin exception ----- 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:  
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:  
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner: mismatch_field:   android.os.Build#BOARD(java.lang.String) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at android.tests.sigtest.SimpleSignatureTest.testSignature(SimpleSignatureTest.java:118) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner:    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1799) 
08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner: ----- end exception ----- 
08-20 15:40:40.967  7195  7208 I TestRunner: finished:
```

From the prints the problem is

`08-20 15:40:40.957  7195  7208 I TestRunner: mismatch_field:   android.os.Build#BOARD(java.lang.String)`

And by looking at Build.java I see it reading from `"ro.product.board"`

`public static final String BOARD = getString("ro.product.board");`(http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/os/Build.java)

after tracing "ro.product.board" for a while I see it is defined in the make file. `/device/abc_company/device_name.mk`

This is totally fine.

But looking at the test case itself, I see it is reading an xml file. It looks this xml file is already in binary (eg. *.apk) so I don't know where it is or what it is.

`start(r.getXml(f.getInt(rClass)));`(ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/sourceforge/s/su/supernovaics/ics/cts/tests/SignatureTest/src/android/tests/sigtest/SimpleSignatureTest.java)

At the very end what I would like to know is where this xml file is.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

o   The expected set is getting generated in api.xml file from the file frameworks/base/api/current.txt 
o   The api.xml file will get generated in the path out/target/common/obj/APPS/SignatureTest_intermediates/api.xml